# Accessing user's own images with monotouch

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an iPhone-application using monotouch. In this app, the user is supposed to get an image already stored in the phone (from the gallery) and bring the selected image into the app. I understand I have to launch a gallery browser of some sort but I haven't found any examples where this is done. Any thoughts on how I should do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nice example: Martin Bowler's [Screen Cast using UIImagePickerController](http://web.archive.org/web/20110414113723/http://martinbowling.com/post/Screen-Cast-Using-UIImagePickerController-in-MonoTouch.aspx)

Comment: How could I miss this?! Thank you very much! It seems to be what I want.